# Image processing with openCV, color change

Tags: c++, image, opencv, colors

I am doing some image processing and I have a black shape on a white image. To use `findContours()` properly I need a white shape on a black image.

1. Is there a way to change openCV settings to track for black shapes on white background instead ?
2. I managed to find white part of the image using `inrange()` I change it to some other color, then change the black part to white, and then again the first part to black all using `inrange()`. But is there a easier way to convert all the black to white and white to black on the image at the same time ?

Comment: You may simply try using `cv::bitwise_not` to invert the image.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Or just write `image = 255 - image` if you have an 8-bit image.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a `binary_image` of type `CV_8UC1`:

1. You can use `binary_not` (as suggested by @ZdaR):

   ```
   binary_not(binary_image, binary_image);
   ```
2. invert the values with an aritmtetic operation (as suggested by @Sunreef):

   ```
   binary_image = 255 - binary_image;
   ```
3. or use the *not* logical operator `~`.

   ```
   binary_image = ~binary_image;
   ```

   This can be a nice shortcut if you just need to invert the values for a particular function, e.g.:

   ```
   findContours(~binary_image, ... );
   ```